# How many real roots does $(x-a)^3+(x-b)^3+(x-c)^3$ have?

Tags: polynomials

Let $a,b,c$ be distinct real numbers. What is the number of distinct real roots of the equation $(x-a)^3+(x-b)^3+(x-c)^3=0$?

1. $1$,
2. $2$,
3. $3$,
4. Depends on the value of $a,b,c$.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Did you try to think of Rolle's theorem?

Comment: @Santosh are you trying to solve NET's question paper?

Comment: neeraj may be you thought

Answer (score 17):

**Hint:**

- Function $f(x) = x^3$ is strictly increasing in $x$.
- Let $f$ and $g$ be strictly increasing, then $x \mapsto f(x)+g(x)$ is strictly increasing as well.

I hope this helps ;-)

Comment: yeap, that's the key, and all that is needed

Answer (score 7):

From the derivative, we see that there is a sum of three squares equalling zero,
$$(x-a)^2+(x-b)^2+(x-c)^2 = 0$$

which implies that for a solution to exist $a=b=c$
Since, given that they are distint, the derivative has no roots.
By Rolle's theorem, we may conclude that the original function may have atmost one root.

Comment: Continuing the answer: "...and since the function is a real polynomial one of odd degree then it has one solution"

Comment: @santoshkumar if you have a polynomial of degree n, then the derivative will be of degree n-1 and hence can admit at most n-1 roots, since the derivative has no roots then the polynomial should be a continuously increasing one(derivative is the slope, right?). Hence, only one root over reals

Comment: i just dont understand by what he means by the existance of a root only if a=b=c. the correct answer is given by me please verify

Comment: @SurajM.S I have made a new explanation in my comment, please refer. I was talking about the roots of the derivative.

Answer (score 6):

Let  $y=(x-a)^3 +(x-b)^3 +(x-c)^3$

then $\dfrac{dy}{dx} =3( (x-a)^2 +(x-b)^2 +(x-c)^2 )$

therefore, $\dfrac{dy}{dx} > 0$

Also, $f(-\infty) = -\infty$ and  $f( \infty ) = \infty$

i.e., $f(x)$ is strictly increasing from $-\infty$ to $\infty$

hence the function possesses $1$ real root for any values of  $a, b ,c$

the number of answers is one.

Comment: This was the most succinct answer to this question I've seen.  Up vote!